# SSAS cube - ordering of measures and dimensions

Tags: ssas, cube

I have inherited several cubes and have learned a bit through doing maintenance and updates to the cubes. One thing I don't understand is "ordering" for measures and dimensions. I use Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 in case it matters. In the dsv, the named queries are all listed in alphabetical order which is perfect. In the cube, however, the Measures and Dimensions are not shown in alphabetical order, and I also don't see an option to sort. Why is that? I have tried to find an answer, and it seems to be to manually drag things into the desired order. But every website I find that says this also has this cryptic statement: "The order will affect how **certain client applications** order these measures." Does anyone know what "certain client applications" refers to? Am I going to cause trouble for myself if I move the Measures and Dimensions around so they are in alphabetical order? There are a lot of dimensions, which is why I want to do this -- I waste so much time manually looking through the list of Dimensions (there are > 70), trying to find the one I want.

The cube also has many calculations (>60), which are also not ordered. Similar question there: could it be problematic if I change the ordering there?

The cube is used by Excel users as well as by dashboards.

Comment: My experience is that Visual Studio shows the order in which it was added, i.e., the project would have started with 10 measures, then the 11th measure would have been added. I don't see an issue in re-ordering. But, why do you want to do it ? For the Excel users, it is always shown in alphabetical order.  Also, for "Calculations", the order may matter !

Answer (score 1):

Update: It's been many months now since I manually reordered my cube measures and dimensions. I have found no ill effects, even with calculations, and it makes it *much* easier to find things. To answer the question "why," it's because my cube has 13 measure groups and about 90 dimensions, and it makes it easier for me to find things while doing active development. Yes, the ordering is automatic for Excel users but it's not automatic for developers.